# CSS: Absolute element relative to inline multiline element

Tags: css, css-position

I have recreated my problem on this pen:
https://codepen.io/brennerp/pen/wOEebK

```css
.example {
  margin-right: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 130px;
  
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  right: -21px;
  
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
    <span>
      <span class="relative">
        <span class="relative__label">
          Wrong one asdsdasadsadsdasadas ts asdsadasdasdsadsajdkhsdjahas
        </span>
        <div class="absolute"></div>
      </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I wanted to have a text of any size with an element absolute-positioned by its end, does not matter what size the text is. I have a relative-positioned inline element with two children: one inline element with its text and other absolute-positioned element with top:0 and right:0.

Just like the "Right one test[...]" example, the little blue circle is at the end and aligns with the middle of the text. However, the "right" property of the absolute element seems to respect one of the SMALLER LINES. In other words, if "right: 0;", the absolute element does not go to the right end of the relative element, but to the end of one of the smaller lines, just like the "Wrong one [...]" example. Which is NOT what I want. I want it to respect the size of the relative element, just like I forced on the CodePen.

Does anyone know the reason for the "right" property to respect the smallest line and not the relative element's width? Is that how inline elements work? Is there a solution for what I want: an absolute element that respects the end of a text element, whether if its 20px or 300px wide (just like the examples I put)?

Comment: and you will have different behavior cross browser .. make your element inline-block

Comment: Thank you, guys. I did not know it was reserved for block elements. Sadly inline-block forces the size.